# Array initializers for pointer variables in C

Tags: c

A function cannot return an array, only a pointer to an array. So I tried doing this:

```
int *arr = {-1, -1};
```

Is that valid syntax? I got a warning from the compiler for that. If not, is there a better way of setting a pointer variable to an array without looping?

Comment: In C99 do: `void* f(){ int size = sizeof(int)*2; return memcopy(malloc(size), (int []){2, 4};, size); }`

Comment: Check [this code](http://ideone.com/HpcLv5)

Comment: You really should read up on the differences between [pointers and arrays](http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/c-faq/c-2.html). But basically, setting a pointer to an array is as easy as `int *ptr = &arr[0];` or even `int *ptr = arr;`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set a pointer to an array created on the fly with a *compound literal*:

```
int *p = (int []){2, 4};
```

However, the array lives only as long as the block it is in. You cannot return it from a function. To return an array (by pointer), you should allocate it dynamically, as with `malloc`.

Comment: Why can't I return it/

Comment: @GeorgeNewton do: `int* f(){ int* p = malloc(sizeof(int)*2); memcopy(p, (int []){2, 4};, sizeof(int)*2); return p;}`

Comment: @GeorgeNewton: Every C object has a lifetime. The lifetime of automatic objects does not extend beyond the execution of the function they are created in (and may end earlier, as when a block finishes executing). Since the object does not exist (in the C model) after the function returns, returning a pointer to it is inappropriate; the pointer would be pointing to space that should not be accessed.

Comment: So everytime I make in array inside a function, it disappears even if I set a pointer variable to it? I absolutely have to malloc for it to stay?

Comment: @GeorgeNewton: Normally, yes. However, you can define an array to be `static`. Such an array will continue to exist after the function returns. However, it will be the same array every time the function is called. If you return a pointer to it, the pointer will be the same every time the function is called; different callers will not get different arrays.

Comment: @GeorgeNewton It could be worse. In C++ that array is so temporary it is destroyed at the end of the initializer expression. I.e. `p` is invalid to dereference as soon as the full expression is finished.

Comment: @GeorgeNewton - If you live through the painful phases of learning it, C is likely the  single most portable, versatile, universally useful languages you will find.  It is used in more areas of programming than any other single language I am aware of:  application, library (both user mode and kernal mode), embedded,... et. al.  and on more OS's.  Windows, linux, Mac,...  So, stay with it.

Answer (score 6):

No. This is not a valid syntax. A valid syntax which could be a pointer to a [compound literal](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2.2/gcc/Compound-Literals.html) is

```
int *arr = (int []){-1, -1};  // Valid only in C99 and latter
```

If you wanna return an array then return a pointer to it;

```
int *arr = malloc(sizeof(*arr)*2);
....
return arr;
```

Comment: So in this case is there a shortcut way to initialize the array without looping?

Comment: A valid declaration in c99 can be `int *arr = (int*){-1, -1};`

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan; But how would you return it from your function? Compound literals are created "on the fly".

Comment: @GeorgeNewton  you can use `memcpy(arr, (int []){ -1, -1}, sizeof(int)*2);` But still you have to use malloc to allocate memory if you wants to return from function.

Comment: @haccks No we can't  it has life within function only.

Comment: @haccks I post a link to question.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan; Yes I can see.

Comment: Doing `int * arr = malloc(2 * sizeof(*arr));` would be saver.

Comment: @alk; I think you mean `arr*`?

Comment: No, I meant exactly what I wrote: "Give me the size of what `arr` points to." Such construct would survive a change in declaration of `arr` without touching the parameter to `malloc()`! This follows the paradigm: "Don't repeat yourself!"

Comment: @alk It can be written like: `int * arr = malloc(2 * sizeof * arr );`  also.  ?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: Sure, but could you still read it, once written? ;-)

Answer (score 2):

`Is there a better way of setting a pointer variable to an array without looping?`

There is a option called pointer to an array. 
**sample:**

```
int a[10];
int (*x)[10] = &a;
```

Answer (score 0):

`arr` is pointer to `integer`. So you can not have multiple inits like this.

You can have below:

```
int *arr = NULL;

arr = malloc(..)

...
...
arr[0] = some value..
arr[1] = some value..
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding

```
int *arr = {-1, -1};
```

*Is that valid syntax?*

***No, but this is:***

```
int *arr = {0}; //initialize pointer to 0;

arr = malloc(100*sizof(int));// allocate memory (can also do this at creation of arr) 

arr[99]=1; //assign value to elements as needed  

free(arr);// free memory when done with arr
```

***And - in this form (pointer)***, `arr` ***is*** returnable by a function:

```
int * somefunc(int *arr)
{
    //manipulate arr[0] - arr[n]
    ....
    return arr;
}
```